# Primitives in unique factorisation domains

Tags: ring-theory, unique-factorization-domains

### Problem

Let R be a UFD, $f = a_0 + a_1 X + ... + a_n X^n \in R[X]$, where f is primitive.
Suppose $p \in R$ is
irreducible with $p \mid a_i$, $0 \le i \lt n$, $p^2 \nmid a_0$, $p \nmid a_n$.

To show f is irreducible, we argue
by contradiction: Assume $f = gh$ where $g,h \in R[X]$, $g = b_0 + b_1 X + ... + b_r X^r$, $h = c_0 + c_1 X + ... + c_s X^s $
, where $r, s \ge 1$.

1. Show that $p \mid b_0$ or $p \mid c_0$, but not both. Also show that $p \nmid b_r$ and $p \nmid c_s$.
2. Suppose $p \mid b_0$. Let k be the smallest positive integer so that $p \nmid b_k$. Show that
   $k \lt n$ and $p \nmid a_k$.

### Attempted Solution

We know that $p \mid a_0$, which means $p \mid b_0 c_0$, since $f=gh$. Because p is irreducible, and in a UFD, we know p is prime, so $p \mid b_0$ or $p \mid c_0$. If it divides both, $ p^2 \mid a_0$, which contradicts assumptions.

Since $p \nmid a_n$, $p \nmid c_s b_r$. This means $p \nmid c_s$ and $p \nmid b_r$, by negating $ p \mid ab \iff p \mid a \lor p \mid b  $

Comment: Thoughts/attempts?

Comment: I edited the question with my attempt at the first part.

Comment: Suppose it does divide both. Then what do you know about $b_0c_0$? For the next part of 1., consider the coefficient of $X^n$.

Comment: Ahh, because if it divides both, $ p^2 \mid a_0 $

Comment: Indeed. For the next part, if $p$ does divide one of them then it divides their product, yielding another contradiction. It's worth justifying/briefly mentioning *why* $a_n=c_sb_r$ - since it doesn't usually hold outside of an integral domain (e.g. consider $(2X+1)(X+1) = X$ in $\mathbb{Z}_2[X]$ - which clearly occurs as an example since we can have $ab=0$ without $a,b=0$ in such cases)

Comment: What is $Z_2[X]$?

Comment: The ring of polynomials with coefficients either $0$ or $1$ i.e. $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is the ring of integers modulo 2. The example was just supposed to illustrate why it's important to respect that $R[X]$ is an integral domain (which it is, as $R[X]$ is a UFD) - it's not directly relevant to the question.